# $G$-invariant functions on Manifolds

Tags: symplectic-geometry, locally-compact-groups, geometric-invariant

In a paper I saw the following statement:

Let $M$ be a connected symplectic manifold and $G$ be a compact Liegroup acting symplectically and hamiltonian on $M$. Let $\Phi \colon M \to \mathfrak{g^*}$ be the corresponding $G$-equivariant momentum map w.r.t. the coadjoint-action on $\mathfrak{g^*}$. Let $s$ be the codimension of a maximal dimensional orbit in $\mathfrak{g^*}$ contained in $\Phi(M)$.

Then there exists $s$  $G$-invariant functions $f_1, \dots f_s \colon \Phi(M)\to \mathbb{R}$, such that for almost all $x\in M$ we have $df_1 \wedge\dots\wedge df_s(\Phi(x))\neq 0 $.

It would be great, if someone could provide some ideas how to prove this statement.

Comment: Have you tried asking on MathOverflow? it's more research oriented and may be best suited to your question

Comment: I didn't know if this question is "advanced enough" to post it at MathOverflow. But I will do it now. Thank you very much.